# Writing an Extend Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if someone could help me to understand ***why*** it is necessary to add the following line...

```
if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
```

... in the following method:

```
extend: function(obj) {
  // shallow copy
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
      this[key] = obj[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the question *why* that line is necessary? Do you understand what [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) < don't be misled by the title, lots of excellent examples about what `hasOwnProperty` is for,

Comment: yes, I do not understand why, as it seems to me the object would always have the key as a property.

Comment: @user2111743 " The purpose of the for-in statement is to enumerate over object properties, this statement will go up in the prototype chain, enumerating also inherited properties, thing that sometimes is not desired." there are tons of posts on SO and internet about reasons to use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @dm03514: It does have good answers, but they do fairly center on the array-ness of the question. :-)

Comment: From the MDN docs for `hasOwnProperty` - "this method does not check down the object's prototype chain". And from the MDN docs for `for in` - "The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `for-in` to loop through the names of the properties of an object, you see **all** of the enumerable properties, including those the object inherits from its prototype. It would appear that the person implementing that method didn't want to copy properties inherited from the prototype, and so only included ones that the object itself directly owns.

Here's an example:

```
function Thing(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Thing.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log("I'm " + this.name);
};
Thing.prototype.infoForAllThings = 42;
var t1 = new Thing("Fred");
console.log(t1.name);             // "Fred"
console.log(t1.infoForAllThings); // "42"
t1.speak();                       // "I'm Fred"
var t2 = extend(t1);              // (Where `extend` is like your function,
                                  // but returns the object rather than using `this`
console.log(t2.name);             // "Fred"
console.log(t2.infoForAllThings); // "undefined"
t2.speak();                       // Error
```

In the above, `t1` inherits the `infoForAllThings` and `speak` properties from its prototype, which gets set to `Thing.prototype` when `t1` is created. But the `extend` function uses `hasOwnProperty` to filter those out, so doesn't copy them to the copy it creates, and so they don't exist on `t2`. `t2` has `name` because that's been assigned *directly* to the object, it doesn't come from the prototype, but the others come from the prototype and so don't get copied.